# Change div color within ajax callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

The initial idea is to select dates from a calendar,[image: The dates which have a frame around them (june 1,june 5, june 6.....etc)] pass the selected dates through ajax and then echo only the selected dates on the calendar(holidays). I query the database for the selected dates and want them to be shown in a different color. 
Here is my ajax function:

```
function save_datepicker_date(date) {


var url     = "/ajax/days_off_add_remove.php";
var params  = {
    date    : date ,
    company_id : $("#company_id").val(),
    field   : "ui-state-highlight"

};

$.get(url, params,
    function(data) {

            alert(data);
        $('.'+field).css("color","#5500ff");

    });
```

}

I don't know why, but this doesn't seem to work. Any help is greatly appreciated!

This is my days_off_add_remove.php file :

```
enter code here   $company_id = $_REQUEST['company_id'];
  $date = $_REQUEST['date'];


$qry = "INSERT INTO days_off SET

                date        = '".mysql_date($date)."',
                company_id = '".$company_id."'


            ";
```

$sql->query($qry);

When i select a date it echoes out the field parameter, which has a value "ui-state-highlight", but it still doesn't work.

SOLVED

Addition: Okay, so now i have the selected holidays in red. 
[image]

What i want to do now is, if someone clicks on a highlighted in red date, it becomes a normal date(not a holiday anymore). Right now I'm trying to select the elements which have the class ui-state-highlight(the red colored squares)...is this the proper way to go? Any suggestions and solutions are welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is `data` you get from the server? I mean which format is it: xml, html, json?

Comment: What do you mean "this doesn't seem to work"? You're chaning a general CSS property in the callback. So this should work if the callback is executed. Are you sure the `$.get`-callback function (`function(data) {...}`) is even executed? You can check this by adding an `alert("Test");` call to the function.

Comment: Yes, it gets executed. The picture i uploaded is showing the selected dates which i pass trough ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
 function save_datepicker_date(date) {


var url     = "/ajax/days_off_add_remove.php";
var params  = {
    date    : date ,
    company_id : $("#company_id").val()

};

$.get(url, params,
    function(data) {

        $('.ui-state-highlight a').css({"background": "none", "background-color":"red"});

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$.getJSON("/ajax/days_off_add_remove.php" + request.term , function (data){
    response($.map(data,function(opt){
        return {
            label : opt.name,
            value : opt.name,

        }
    }))
})
```